# Деление массива Scala, Ocaml

Tags: scala, ocaml

Задание: Напишите функцию, которая генерирует другую функцию (factory (??)). Функция должна выполнять следующее: принять массив целых чисел и разделить его на три массива ([числа которые делятся на х], [числа которые делятся на у], [все остальные числа]). x,y должны быть переданы как параметры генеративной функции. Используйте соответствие шаблону (match the pattern), хвостовую рекурсию и  анонимные функции. Внимание! Каждый элемент массива может быть проверен только 1 раз. Нельзя пользоваться готовыми библиотечными функциями. Выполните задание хотя бы в одном из языков: Scala или OCaml.
Пример(OCaml):

```
    let groupingFunction = generateGroupingFunctionFactory 3 5;;
    groupingFunction [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10] => ([3;6;9],[5,10],[1;2;4;7;8]);;
```

Вот что у меня есть на данный момент(Ocaml):

```
   let generateGroupingFunctionFactory x y =
let rec generate list =
    match list with
        [] -> ([],[],[])
        | (hd::tail) when hd mod x = 0 -> 
            match generate tail with
                (x,y,rest) -> (hd::x,y,rest)
        | (hd::tail) when hd mod y = 0 ->
            match generate tail with
                (x,y,rest) -> (x,hd::y,rest)
        | (hd::tail) ->
            match generate tail with
                (x,y,rest) -> (x,y,hd::rest)
in generate;;

let groupingFunction = generateGroupingFunctionFactory 3 5;;
groupingFunction [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10];;
```

Но я не до конца понимаю что в этом коде можно выразить в виде анонимной функции и как написать функцию которая генерирует другую функцию. Буду рад любой помощи либо информации на эту тему.

Comment: Для того чтоб сделать функцию. генерирующую другую функцию, можете каррировать ту, что Вы написали. Сейчас вы сразу передаете в нее 3 аргумента. Как вариант можете передать сперва лист, а потом уже применять его клюбым двум числам.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итоговый вариант в Scala:

```
def generateGroupingFunctionFactory(x: Int, y: Int): List[Int] => (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = {
  def generate(list: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = {
    def generateHelper(listIn: List[Int], listX: List[Int], listY: List[Int], listRest: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) =
      listIn match {
        case Nil => (listX, listY, listRest)
        case head::tail => (head%x==0, head%y==0) match {
            case (true, true) => generateHelper(tail, listX:::List(head), listY:::List(head), listRest)
            case (true, false) => generateHelper(tail, listX:::List(head), listY, listRest)
            case (false, true) => generateHelper(tail, listX, listY:::List(head), listRest)
            case (false, false) => generateHelper(tail, listX, listY, listRest:::List(head))
          }
      }
    generateHelper(list, List(), List(), List())
  }
  generate
}

def groupingFunction = generateGroupingFunctionFactory(4,7)
def test = assert(groupingFunction(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15))==(List(4,8,12),List(7,14),List(1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,15)))
test
```

Всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

def generateGroupingFunctionFactory(x: Int, y: Int): List[Int] => (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = {
  val splitByX = ListBuffer.empty[Int]
  val splitByY = ListBuffer.empty[Int]
  val other = ListBuffer.empty[Int]

  @tailrec
  def go(input: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = {

    input match {
      case Nil => (splitByX.toList, splitByY.toList, other.toList)
      case head :: tail =>

        val canDivideByX = head % x == 0
        val canDivideByY = head % y == 0

        if (canDivideByX) splitByX += head
        if (canDivideByY) splitByY += head
        if (!(canDivideByX || canDivideByY)) other += head

        go(tail)
    }
  }

  go
}

val groupingFunction = generateGroupingFunctionFactory(3, 5)

groupingFunction((1 to 10).toList) // (List(3, 6, 9),List(5, 10),List(1, 2, 4, 7, 8))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я уверен что он будет правильно работать, но его все равно посчитают неправильным, так, как нас пытаются обучить чистому функциональному мышлению на сколько я понял. Разрешают пользоваться только рекурсией (никаких петлей) и без создания переменных внутри методов (оперировать только на данных, передаваемых функции).